# JSON parse sorting in a loop

Tags: javascript, json

I am working on this code and need to sort the JSON output by a value, in this case called cars. How can I accomplish it in this code?

```
var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    txtFile.open("GET", "test.txt", true);
    txtFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (txtFile.readyState === 4) {  
        if (txtFile.status === 200) {  // Makes sure it's found the file.
          allText = txtFile.responseText;
          lines = txtFile.responseText.split("\n"); // Will separate each line into an array

          for (var i = 0; i <= lines.length; i++){

              var obj = JSON.parse(lines[i]);

                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += obj._serverMessages[0].car + "         " + obj.creator.substr(2, obj.creator.length) + " / " + obj._serverMessages[0].content + "<br>";


          }
        }
      }
    }
    txtFile.send(null);
```

Comment: Please show a sample of your json

Comment: What do you mean "sort" - sort what data and by which criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code will give you the result you were looking for:

```
var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
txtFile.open("GET", "test.txt", true);
txtFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (txtFile.readyState === 4) {  
        if (txtFile.status === 200) {  // Makes sure it's found the file.
            allText = txtFile.responseText;
            lines = txtFile.responseText.split("\n"); // Will separate each line into an array

            var array = [];
            for (var i = 0; i <= lines.length; i++) {
                array.push(JSON.parse(lines[i]))
            }
            array.sort(function(a, b){
                if (a._serverMessages && a._serverMessages.length && a._serverMessages[0] && a._serverMessages[0].car) {
                    if (b._serverMessages && b._serverMessages.length && b._serverMessages[0] && b._serverMessages[0].car) {
                        return a._serverMessages[0].car > b._serverMessages[0].car? 1 : -1;
                    } else return -1;
                } else return 1;
            });

            for (var i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += array[i]._serverMessages[0].car + "         " + array[i].creator.substr(2, array[i].creator.length) + " / " + array[i]._serverMessages[0].content + "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
txtFile.send(null);
```

Comment: Virgilio, thanks for the answer but that did not work for some reason and I also did not see any errors in the console.

Comment: Try to debug and check the array before and after sort. Is it not sorting by the property _serverMessages[0].car as you wanted?

Comment: Virgilio, the content is not shown at all. I will try to debug and will let you know what I learn. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey Virgilio, sorry for the late response but I can't still get it to work. I got an example from my json response, I wanted to sort by the originalarrivaltime in this example: https://pastebin.com/1zysxJ0C. Any other idea? Thank you!